# Is Kanji no longer allowed on this site?

Tags: support, bug

Can we still use kanji?  I get a `Body cannot contain "<>"` when I try to paste some in either comments or question/answer edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We blocked Chinese characters (which is a Unicode character categorization that Kanji falls under) across the network about a week ago, as we were being hit by Chinese spammers on many sites.

It was only ever hit once here, so I have removed the block on the site.

Kanji on to your hearts content.

Comment: Thanks for that!  If we get hit, I am sure someone will report it.